# Issue with workTime class in PHP

Tags: php

I'm having a few problems with a PHP class which I didn't write.

1. I need to calculate the interval between dates with calendar days (not with workweek(1 day = 8h )). 
   Example: Today(03-02-2017 (13:45:20)) I create a task with deadline 10-02-2017(23:59:59).

   1.1 The term days must be 7, not 5, and hours are not important.
2. Honestly, I can't figure out this code. Can someone point me in the right direction? I need to know where what to change or calculate is.

I'll leave a gist link instead of code because it's too long.

https://gist.github.com/biboletin/f862b898466dfb9057e8dd9f710db1fd

Comment: `$days = round((strtotime($dateTo) - strtotime($dateFrom)) / 86400);`

Comment: nope, the days now are 4, must be 7. I still think i dont say everything but if someone have questions...

Comment: You sure about that? https://3v4l.org/69vHi. That code is just an expanded version of what I wrote above and works as expected. Really though, you should probably use a [DateTime](https://php.net/datetime) object, but this is sort of the quick-and-dirty (tm) way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

I examined your workTime class and I think you have everything done. There is a method `setDate_Diff()` (called in `construct()`), which calculates variable `intDays`. IMHO this is what you need.

Additionaly there is a method `getDiffInDays()` in your class, which returns you value of intDays...

Comment: you made me track more carefully the code, i decided to create method for this task(im sure about that the solution is under my eyes but i cant catch the logic)... thanks

Comment: The logic is simple - when you create object out of workTime class e.g. $wt = new workTime("03-02-2017 13:45:20", "10-02-2017 23:59:59") then the construct method itself calls setDate_Diff() method, which calculates diiference in days, hours and minutes into intDays, intHours, intMinutes and intSeconds. Then you can access it by calling $wt->getDiffInDays(), $wt->getDiffInHours and $wt->getDiffInMinutes. It's o.k. to create another method for learning porposes, but I don't recomend to duplicate code for same tasks in production code...

Comment: i think i got it. I think the problem is not in class calculations, its about the global variables: SWH, EWH etc. placed in whole different file